# Prisma, how to see relational foreign key id?

Tags: mysql, prisma

Prisma, how to see relational foreign key id?

They say when you do this

```
await ctx.prisma.post.create({
        data: {
          title: input.title,
          content: input.content,
          contentHtml: markdownToHtml(input.content),
          author: {
            connect: {
              id: ctx.session.user.id,
            },
          },
        },
      })
```

It says "connect:" automatically connects. However, when I enter the database on planet scale and check, the corresponding column does not exist. How is this data permanently preserved? Also where can I extract it?

Comment: Have a look at your `schema.prisma`. Probably there is a field like `authorId`.

Comment: What do you mean with the corresponding column does not exist? Also note that [PlanetScale doesn't have FKs](https://planetscale.com/docs/learn/operating-without-foreign-key-constraints). Nonetheless, your `Post` model probably has a field that's called `authorId` (or smth similar) that represents the _reference_ to the the `Author` model (assuming it's called like this but not sure). This field should be set after you called `connect`. (It would also be helpful if you could share your schema btw).

Comment: @nburk but prisma has previewFeatures = ["referentialIntegrity"] isn`t it ? In a typical mysql database, foreign_key_column exists in the database. But in Vitess it doesn't exist. Where are they being stored?

Comment: @some-user yah thats what I`m saying.. It does not exist in the database, it exists only in prisma.schema. How do I check which one is connected and how?

Comment: Here's an in-depth discussion about referential integrity on PlanetScale with really great insight: https://github.com/planetscale/discussion/discussions/74#discussioncomment-1196261